# Explain variable declaration and output in this example

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

I'm confused at this example:

```
int x = 5;
if (x==5) cout << x; // output 5
if (x==6) cout << x;
if (x=6) cout << x; // output 6
x = 0;
if (x=0) cout << x;
x = 5;
if (x-5) cout << x;
if (x-6) cout << x; // output 5
```

I understand first `if (x==5)`, but why does it output 6 at `if (x=6)` when x = 5, and why won't it output 0 in `if(x=0)`

Comment: Think about what this means: `x=6`.

Comment: Operators `=` (assignment), `==` (equal to) are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (x=6)
```

means not comparison, but assignment. You assign 6 to x and the return value of the expression is 6, which is not 0 so it gains true.

similar with `if (x=0)` The expression x=0 gains 0 so it means `if(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The thing about computers is that they're *extraordinarily* literal. A missing semicolon, or an added character, can completely change a program's function. So you need to be just as careful as a computer when working wth programs.

As @juanchopanza alluded to, there is a difference between `==` and `=` - and you already know what it is.